# how to get all the users from the list in twitter?

Tags: python, twitter

I want to get all the user from a list using twitter api. But i have some query regarding this. Does this needs oauth authentication? I am using python.

Answer (score 1):

Returning the members of a [specified list](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/%3auser/%3alist_id/members) does require authentication.